# Why five brothers of bride are invited in "chori/mandap" while marriage is going on and what ritual is performed for what results?

Tags: rituals, marriage

I have seen till date that in Hindu wedding ceremony five brothers are asked or invited to do some ritual.

They just drop some piece of tree in their sister's jholi one by one and some hymns or mantras are sung by officiating priest.

By the law of karma, If you give something along with mantra, there must be some reason behind good wish for sister.

But I want to know what is that ritual and what are the results of it.

Why five brothers of bride are invited in "chori/mandap" while marriage and what ritual is performed and for what results?

[image]

Comment: @Partha Chori means what?

Comment: Chori means the stage or place where rituals are peroformed.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi If 5 brothers are not available then what shortcut is employed?Is 5 brothers from the same mother is what u meant?

Comment: Cousines or friends are called, it is consider that brother has to give something to sister in that ritual. But what sacrifice they ask is important to know.

Comment: Do they put puffed rice? Or  part of trees compulsory?

Comment: I've never heard of it, I think its not very popular custom or has limited influence over some state or region in India.